# Copying Cells in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm try to copy a column, where each cells has two numbers separated by a slash, e.g, R24/6258.

When I try to drag down the cell that contains R24/6258, each cell still has R24, but increases from 6258. For example, the first cell contains R24/6258, the next cell contains R24/6259, the next contains R24/6260, and so on.

So is there any way, without manually typing out these numbers, for the first cell to contain R24/6258 and then the following cell contains R25/6259?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a non-standard format which Excel only recognizes the last part of. To increment the format you have shown, I would do it in the following manner.

1. Enter `R24` in one column and drag it down the number of rows you
   desire.
2. Enter `6258` in the next column and drag it down the number of rows
   you desire.
3. In the third column, use a `CONCATENATE` formula to bring it all
   together.
4. Copy the formula to the rest of the cells in the column.

In my example below, I used `=CONCATENATE(A1, "/", B1)` to create the format you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way, but you can just put the R24 in one column, then the 6259 in the column next to it and drag them both. Next next to those, just concatenate them back.